# JS Event listener for dynamic added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a few buttons dynamically based on a JSON object through a loop. I want it to be able to pass the correct index when the save button is click.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.results.length; i++) {
    var row = `<tr scope="row" class="test-row-${jsonObject.results[i].id}">
                    ...
                  
                  <td id="btn-list">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-testid="${jsonObject.results[i].id}" id="delete-${jsonObject.results[i].id}">Delete</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" disabled data-testid="${jsonObject.results[i].id}"  id="save-${jsonObject.results[i].id}">Save</button>
                  </td>
    </tr>`;

$(`#save-${jsonObject.results[i].id}`).on('click', saveUpdate(i))
}
```

the current save button auto-trigger saveUpdate() and pass in every index

```
    $(document).on('click', `#save-${jsonObject.results[i].id}`, function(){
      saveUpdate(i);
    });

    $(`#save-${jsonObject.results[i].id}`).click(function(){
      saveUpdate(i);
    });
```

The two event listeners wait for the click but will pass in the `jsonObject.results.length` instead of the index that it was clicked.

Comment: use `class` and `data` attribute instead of `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because of Hoisting. **i** variable is created by **var** keyword, and in the loop, you are binding the event. As **var** have functional scope, it preserve it value and even after binding the event, when it access it got the last value, that is your array length.

use **let** instead it will work. **let** have block scope. Rest seems fine. It will work

```
for (let i = 0; i < jsonObject.results.length; i++) {
}
```